# Can I replace my Linux installation with another one (without breaking my Windows dual boot)?

Tags: linux, multi-boot

I have Linux Mint installed alongside Windows 7. I want to install Backtrack Linux instead of Mint.

One of my friends said that if I installed it I would lose my Windows 7, and now I'm afraid to do so.

Is that true? If not, how can I replace Mint with Backtrack?

Comment: Do you use Microsoft bootloader or GRUB currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insall BT5 over the CentOS partition and then run a Windows repair with your CD in order to fix the bootloader.

Comment: Wouldn't the Linux installation take care of installing GRUB and fixing it automatically from the partitions found?

Comment: I can only speak from my experience installing Backtrack alongside Windows.

Comment: @slhck it should, but sometimes things go weird. It's always possible to boot into a live environment, mount, chroot, and reinstall grub manually too. I've had to do it a few times while I was messing around with things I shouldn't have.